# Question on Dirac Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, notation

I understand that the ket $|x>$ can be written in matrix form as:
\begin{equation}
|x>=\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
But what is the matrix representation of a ket such as |1>?

Comment: Are you asking about the first excited state of the quantum harmonic oscillator? Or the state with x=1 ?

Comment: The stuff inside a ket is just a label. It is often a summary of the relevant quantum numbers for the state, so the label can be a tuple of several quantum numbers. A famous example is the label attached to eigenstates of the hydrogen atom, where the label consists of three relevant quantum numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The vector notation depends on the basis. If you have two levels $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, then you can assign 2d vectors as

$$|0\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$|1\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
but this is just a choice, we could have chosen the opposite,
$$|0\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$|1\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
or we could choose something more elaborate as
$$|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$|1\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}-\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

as long as the vectors remain orthogonal everything is ok.

Note that if you have three states like $|0\rangle$,$|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ you'll need three dimensional vectors and so on.

Another important remark is that this notation does not work well when the basis is infinite like in the case of a harmonic oscillators where the basis is $|n\rangle$ where $n$ can be any non-negative integer. Another example are the position eigenstates where the $x$ in $|x\rangle$ can usually be any real value.

Conclusion, it is up to you (or the author of whatever text your are reading) to choose the basis/representation.